# MSMQ Private queue limitations

Tags: msmq

In My application we are thinking on creating multiple private queue for processing different task so please any one let me know if i have 1000 of private queue for processing the different messages Is there any impact on msmsq processing if i create multiple private queue

Comment: Why would you need 1000 queues?

Comment: Ours is not to question why, but to help understand. 2 reasons, huge system or bad design - those are usually the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The question, as I understand it, is - will my application suffer if I use multiple private queues instead of one.

It's not a technical problem if you have multiple message queues other than the fact that one would typically do this in order to separate "purposes" and perhaps get more control on the whole transmission/reception.

Personally, I wouldn't create multiple queues unless you are stuck in a situation where you simply can't solve your problem without many of them - i think that 1000 is overboard and you may have a design issue and you are using multiple queues in order to circumvent the design flaw.

Or, you are building a huge system (like we do here, we have more than 1000 queues here and we have a very good design and know our stuff).

The main problem that I see here is that I'm getting the feeling that most (if not all) of those queues will be used by a single application on perhaps a non-(or little-)distributed system.

Consider this: If you have multiple mailboxes for receiving snail mail, you have to manually check each and every one of them any time you need to process your own mail (pay bills, etc). In the computer world it's the same problem, you are going to have to come up with a strategy that will check all those queues. If it's distributed it's ok (the whole purpose usually is to have 1 queue per computer, in case you need to use direct messaging for any reason) but if it's all on the same machine then you will actually need to program a huge loop which will eventually be slow and you will not get the performance that you would be getting should you were using a single queue.

Hope this helps,